# Application for making diagrams on OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, diagrams, visualization

I have got some data that I want to visualize.

Is there any specific app for this (not Excel or OpenOfice or Numbers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to use [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for making network diagrams - it's similar to Visio in alot of ways.

Comment: And not similar in the ways Visio use causes pain :-)

Comment: Can it automatically generate castom diagrams for my data?

Comment: castom? general fidel castom?

Comment: I mean custom :)